# using knockout attr data-binding to display icons <i> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Regular icon tag is normally used this way:

```
<i class="fa fa-cultery"></i>
```

but for some reason I tried to store the icon class names inside a viewModel like:

```
        self.interviewScheduleIconOptions = [
            "icon-chair",
            "icon-clock",
            "icon-dollar",
            "icon-monitor",
            "icon-star",
            "icon-subway",
        ];
```

and tried to do something like

```
<i data-bind="attr: {class: $data}"></i>
```

before this, I tried to test

to see if it works with data-bind.

The icon did not appear and when I inspected the HTML, it gave me:

```
<i data-bind="attr: {class: 'fa fa-cultery'}" class="fa fa-cultery"></i>
```

so it gave the right class, but the icon did not appear.

Any idea?

Comment: can you please try `<i data-bind="attr: {'class': $data}"></i>`

which means single quote around `class`

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great !!
Please accept and upvote the answer, it will help close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `<i data-bind="attr: {'class': $data}"></i>` which means single quote around class

**Reason**

Because, `class` is not a legal javascript variable name
Note: Applying attributes whose names aren’t legal JavaScript variable names

If you want to apply the attribute data-something, you can’t write this:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { data-something: someValue }">...</div>
```

… because `data-something` isn’t a legal identifier name at that point. The solution is simple: just wrap the identifier name in quotes so that it becomes a string literal, which is legal in a JavaScript object literal. For example,

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'data-something': someValue }">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be referring to two different versions of font-awesome. Classes like `fa fa-search` belong to [FA 4.7.2](http://fontawesome.io/icons/). While classes like `icon-search` belong to [version 3.2.1](http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icons/)

You can use the `css` binding which is meant to be used for CSS classes.

```
<i data-bind="css: $root.class"></i>
```

Font-Awesome 4.7.2

```js
var Model = function() {
  var self= this;
  
  self.class= ko.observable( "fa fa-search");
}

ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i data-bind="css: $root.class"></i>
```

Font-Awesome 3.2.1

```js
var Model = function() {
  var self= this;
  
  self.class= ko.observable( "icon-search");
  
  self.interviewScheduleIconOptions = ko.observableArray([
            "icon-chair",
            "icon-clock",
            "icon-dollar",
            "icon-monitor",
            "icon-star",
            "icon-subway",
        ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i data-bind="css: $root.class"></i>

<span data-bind="foreach: interviewScheduleIconOptions">
  <br/>
  <span data-bind="text: ($index() + 1)"></span>
  <i data-bind="css: $data"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use " <i data-bind="css : $data "></i>" but it gives me the "before" status when I inspect the html. Thus, the icon does not appear. Do you know why?

Comment: I have edited my example to show how you could use an array of icon classes. Also see that some of the icons in your list are not showing up because they aren't supported in version 3.2.1. You can see the list of supported icons here: http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icons/